# SQLite database disappeared from Android emulator

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator, kotlin

I'm working in Android Studio 3.0.1 and using Android emulator to see how application run. I had SQLite database for my application but after update of Android Studio or maybe its components emulator started with message "performing clean boot snapshot doesn't exist". My database disappeared from application. Is that some wipe on Android emulator or I've made some mistake in database programming? Can this trouble happens on real device?

```
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder
import android.widget.Toast
import android.database.SQLException
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList


class DbManagerVol {
    var dbName=Const.DB_NAME
    var dbTable:String? = null
    val dbVersion = 2
    var sqlCreateTable:String? = null 
    var sqlDB:SQLiteDatabase? = null

    constructor (context: Context, dbTable:String?, sqlCreateTable:String?) {
        this.sqlCreateTable = sqlCreateTable
        this.dbTable = dbTable
        val db = DataBaseHelperVol(context)
        sqlDB=db.writableDatabase
        if(sqlCreateTable!=null)sqlDB!!.execSQL(sqlCreateTable)
    }

    inner class DataBaseHelperVol:SQLiteOpenHelper {
        var context:Context?=null
        constructor(context: Context):super(context,dbName,null,dbVersion){
            this.context=context
        }
        override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {

            db!!.execSQL(sqlCreateTable)
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "database $dbName is created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
            db!!.execSQL("Drop table IF EXISTS $dbTable")
        }

    }
    fun dbInsert(values:ContentValues):Long{
        val ID = sqlDB!!.insert(dbTable, "", values)
        return ID
    }

    fun dbQuery(projection: Array<String>, selection:String, selectionArgs:Array<String>, sortOrder:String):Cursor?{
        val qb = SQLiteQueryBuilder()
        qb.tables=dbTable
        var cursor:Cursor? = null
        try {
            cursor = qb.query(sqlDB, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder)
        }catch (e:Exception){}
        return cursor!!
    }

    fun dbQueryArray(projection: Array<String>, selection:String, selectionArgs:Array<String>, sortOrder:String,
                      spUndefined:String, spAdd:String, spDelete:String):ArrayList<String>{
        val listSpinner:ArrayList<String>? = ArrayList<String>()
        val qb = SQLiteQueryBuilder()
        qb.tables=dbTable

        try {
            val cursor:Cursor? = qb.query(sqlDB, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder)
            if (cursor!!.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    val str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(sortOrder))
                    listSpinner!!.add(str)

                } while (cursor.moveToNext())
            }
            listSpinner!!.add(spUndefined)
            listSpinner.add(spAdd)
            listSpinner.add(spDelete)

        } catch (e:SQLException) {
            listSpinner!!.add(spUndefined)
            listSpinner.add(spAdd)
            listSpinner.add(spDelete)
        }

        return listSpinner!!
    }
    
    fun dbRowDelete(colName:String, value:String):Int {
        sqlDB!!.execSQL(sqlCreateTable)
        val str2 = "$colName='$value'"
        return sqlDB!!.delete(dbTable, str2, null)
    }
    
    fun dbLastRowInt(dbTable:String, column:String):Int {
        val selectQuery= "SELECT * FROM $dbTable ORDER BY $column DESC LIMIT 1"
        val cursor = sqlDB!!.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
        var a = 0
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            a  =  cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex(column) )
        cursor.close()
        return a


    }
    
    fun dbUpdateRow (table:String, values: ContentValues, colName:String, value:Int):Int {
        return sqlDB!!.update(table, values, "$colName = $value", null)
    }

    fun dbDelTable () {
        sqlDB!!.execSQL("Drop table IF EXISTS $dbTable")
    }

    fun dbRowsDelete(colName:String, values:Array<String>):Int {
        sqlDB!!.execSQL(sqlCreateTable)
        val placeholders = StringBuilder()
        for (i in 0 until values.size) {
            if (i != 0)
                placeholders.append(", ")

            placeholders.append("?")
        }

        val where = "$colName IN (" + placeholders.toString() + ")"
        return sqlDB!!.delete(dbTable, where, values)
    }

    fun countTables () :ArrayList<String>{
        val array = ArrayList<String>()
        val c = sqlDB!!.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null) 
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while ( !c.isAfterLast) {
                array.add( c.getString( c.getColumnIndex("name")) )
                c.moveToNext()
            }
        }
        return array
    }

}
```

Comment: "I've made some mistake in database programming"   How can anyone analyze that without any code ??

Comment: what have u done ? u installed the app and then you have wiped out the emulator data

Comment: I don't think that the problem is in code really. I  wiped nothing manually.

Comment: If you update system image, all your data in that emulator will be cleared

Answer (score 0):

Your `onUpgrade` method of `DataBaseHelperVol` contains only drop instructions. It means that first version update of database will just clean data. May be you need to exec your `sqlCreateTable` instruction again, but I don't know what you want here.

Guess you don't understand SQLite database lifecycle. [Try to read that](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/).

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will correct this line. But I've never changed database version. As far as I understand onUpgrade method is invoked when version is changed. And I have not this problem before that message "performing clean boot snapshot doesn't exist" appeared.